# List<string> to object[]

Tags: c#

I have a method that returns a `List<string>` and I'm trying to pass that to the `AddRange(Object[])` method of a `ComboBox`.

How can I convert my `List<string>` to `Object[]`?

I suppose I could do a `foreach` but I'd rather use the `AddRange(Object[])` as it's faster (and produces less code).

**EDIT**

The following works fine:

```
var list = new List<string>();
object[] array = list.ToArray<object>();
comboBox.AddRange(array);
```

However, on another note, any reason why I would want to perform the above instead of:

```
var list = new list<string>();
comboBox.AddRange(list.ToArray<object>());
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it using `ToArray` generic method:

```
var list = new List<string>();
object[] array = list.ToArray<object>();
```

You don't even need `Cast<object>`, because `ToArray` takes `IEnumerable<T>` which is covariant on generic type parameter.

Comment: Arrays are also covariant, so you don't even need to do `list.ToArray<object>()`, you can just to `list.ToArray()`.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken: Well, it depends on whether the OP may want to store non-strings in the same array later.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken You can take advantage of that, when calling methods like `AddRange`, but otherwise when you'd like to use that array later I would suggest using `ToArray<object>` instead of array covariance.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken just doing `list.ToArray()` produces a warning saying `Co-variant array conversion from string[] to object[] can cause run-time exception on write operation`.

Comment: @cogumel0 The warning you're quoting is the same Jon Skeet pointed few comments above.

Comment: @cogumel0 I think that's a Resharper warning. (I don't use Resharper so I've never seen it.) It's certainly a good idea to steer clear of array covariance in general, although it shouldn't be an issue in this case if all you're doing is `comboBox.Items.AddRange(myList.ToArray());`. I won't discourage you from working around the warning.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like to be explicit about the change of the type:

```
object[] array = yourList.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
```

or simply be implicit:

```
yourcomboBox.AddRange(yourList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> items = ...;
cb.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

Comment: The only solution here that doesn't forget that arrays are covariant already in C#.

Comment: This produces `Co-variant array conversion from string[] to object[] can cause run-time exception on write operation`, which is why I deviated from it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works:

```
object[] myArray = myList.OfType<object>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays of references are covariant ([slowly covariant](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/)) with arrays of their base classes (and with arrays of their interfaces, and with other arrays), so you can:

```
AddRange(mystrings.ToArray());
```

`mystrings.ToArray()` is a `string[]`, that is covariant with an `object[]` (so that the `AddRange` will accept it)

From [12.5 Array covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> For any two reference-types A and B, if an implicit reference conversion (Section 6.1.4) or explicit reference conversion (Section 6.2.3) exists from A to B, then the same reference conversion also exists from the array type A[R] to the array type B[R]

Answer (score 0):

If it's about convenience:

```
public static class ObjectCollectionExtension
{
    public static void AddAll<T>(this ComboBox.ObjectCollection self, IEnumerable<T> es)
    {
        foreach (var e in es)
            self.Add(e);
    }
}
```

Might have gotten the generics wrong, I'm a bit rusty.